# Email sending fails with all the exceptions

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, email, visual-c++, c++-cli

Please have a look at the following code

**Email.h**

```
    #pragma once
    #include <string>

    using namespace System::Net;
    using namespace System::Net::Mail;
    using namespace System::Net::Mime;

    using namespace std;


    ref class Email
    {
    public:
        Email();

        //Sets the location of the attachment
        void setAttachment(System::String ^attachmentLocation);

        //Set the the from address of the email
        void setFromAddress(System::String ^fromAddress);

        //Set the reception's address of the email
        void setToAddress(System::String ^toAddress);

        //Set the subject pf the email
        void setSubject(System::String ^subject);

        //Set the Message of the email
        void setMessage(System::String ^emailMessage);

        //Set the SMTP client
        void setSMTPClient(System::String ^smtpClient);

        //Send the email
        void sendEmail();

    private:
        MailMessage ^mail;
        Attachment ^attachment;
        SmtpClient ^client;
    };
```

**Email.cpp**

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Email.h"


Email::Email()
{
    mail = gcnew MailMessage();

}

void Email::setAttachment(System::String ^attachmentLocation)
{
    attachment = gcnew Attachment(attachmentLocation);

    ContentDisposition ^disposition = attachment->ContentDisposition;
    disposition->CreationDate = System::IO::File::GetCreationTime(attachmentLocation);
    disposition->ModificationDate = System::IO::File::GetLastWriteTime(attachmentLocation);
    disposition->ReadDate = System::IO::File::GetLastAccessTime(attachmentLocation);
}

void Email::setFromAddress(System::String ^fromAddress)
{
    mail->From = gcnew MailAddress(fromAddress);
}

void Email::setMessage(System::String ^emailMessage)
{
    mail->Body = emailMessage;
}

void Email::setSMTPClient(System::String ^smtpClient)
{
    client = gcnew SmtpClient(smtpClient);
}

void Email::setSubject(System::String ^subject)
{
    mail->Subject = subject;
}

void Email::setToAddress(System::String ^toAddress)
{
    mail->To->Add(toAddress);
}

void Email::sendEmail()
{
    try
    {
        client->Send(mail);
    }
    catch(System::Exception ^e)
    {
        System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show(e->ToString());
    }

}
```

This is how I call this class, in another class

```
Email ^email = gcnew Email();
                     email->setToAddress("sss@yahoo.com");
                     email->setSubject("Intruder Detected");
                     email->setSMTPClient("localhost");
                     email->setMessage("sending mail. Image is attached");
                     email->setFromAddress("justsomemail@lol.com");
                     email->setAttachment("D:/OpenCV Final Year/Images/intruder.bmp");
                     email->sendEmail();
```

Please note that `From` address here is a non existing/not real address. In real code also it is like the same. `To` address is real and modified here because I can't publish the original address.

When I run this code, I get the following error.

[image]

This is my very first attempt in C++/CLI (C++ AND C#) Email sending. I can remember I used `localhost` for my Java applications in Java Mail so I really can't find what is the real error here.

Comment: Do you have an SMTP server running on your local machine?

Comment: @DavidYaw:oops, No. I do have apache James, will it work? Or, I can use google or something isn't it?

Comment: I've never worked with Apache James, but it should work fine as an SMTP server for your code to connect to. You're trying to send email, which is real external connectivity, so you need to give it the real address of a real SMTP server, not necessarily just 'localhost' and hope it works.